# android disabling a button does not work

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to disable the button upon the `onsucceed()` method. But I tried every possible options like `button.setVisibility()`, `button.setEnabled()` but nothing really works. What might be the root cause?

here is my code :

```
 if(device1notConnected) {
      scanneddevice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if(device1notConnected==false)
                     scanneddevice1.setClickable(false);

           device1.connect(new DeviceConnectCallback() {
              @Override
                 public void onSucceed(Device device1, DeviceConnectResult result) {
                                device1notConnected = false;
                                Log.d(TAG, "The connection is successful");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The connection is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // The connection is successful...
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Device device, DeviceCallbackException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Maybe it depends of WHO is the Executor of the "DeviceConnectCallback()". Do you have the source code of "connect()" method? If Yes: you have to check if it uses an Handler or "runOnUiThread()" to execute the "onSucceed()" callback on the UiThread/MainThread, or it is done by the internal WorkerThread (if is used). Did you check that the "onSucceed()" method are well executed to its End when you use "button.setVisibility()"? Because I'm starting to think that the Callback code generates an Exception and it is earlier ended before reach your setVisibility()...

Answer (score 0):

Try calling 'setEnabled(false)' right away in the onClick method (remove device1notConnected boolean and the 'if' check completely).  In 'onError' call 'setEnabled(true)' so that the user can try again or whatever.  If onError is on a background thread then call use the post method on the button and provide a runnable that does 'setEnabled(true)'